# What is the change of "Airspace" here? Does it mean the airspace class of the airport has changed?

Tags: airspace, aeronautical-charts, jeppesen, airspace-classes

What is the change of "Airspace" here? Does it mean the airspace class of the airport has changed? I haven't reached a source where I can find the airspace classes used in my country anyway (Turkey). If what is meant in this question is airspace class, I will be more confused because there is no symbol or text indicating this on Jeppesen charts. If the expression "airspace" mentioned here has a different meaning, what is it? This screenshot is taken from LTBU airport's 11-1 page ILS Z or LOC Z Rwy 04 Jeppesen chart, revision date is 22 OCT 21 and the effective date is 4th of Nov.

[image]

Comment: I recommend you find a copy of the previous revision and see what actually changed.  It's probably either the airspace classification or the boundaries of the airspace itself, but without directly comparing the two you can only speculate as to what may have changed.  As it stands there isn't enough context to answer the question.

Comment: A very sensible approach. I absolutely agree with what you said, if I can understand the difference after comparing it with the previous chart, I will share the answer here. Thanks again..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we examine the 11-1 page of the previously printed chart for LTBU airport, we can clearly understand what the mentioned changes mean. The change we call "**Procedure Title**" is changing the name of the chart from "**ILS Z Rwy 04**" to "**ILS Z or LOC Z Rwy 04**". The meaning of the change indicated by the word "**Airspace**" is the restricted airspace with the code "**LT(R)-40**" added to the southeast of the airport. I am sharing the sections of the two charts so that you can understand the difference. Many thanks to Michael Hall for guiding me to find the answer.

[image]
[image]