# What is the "Change Notices Available" information on the airport information page of the Jeppesen chart?

Tags: aeronautical-charts, jeppesen, aeronautical-information

What is the "Change Notices Available" information on the airport information page of the Jeppesen chart? For some, none is specified, and sometimes different numbers such as four and sometimes two are used. What do these mean? I have shared the airport information page of LTAF and LTBU airports below.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short, it means there have been some number of changes made since the last publication, and those changes are detailed in change notices.

If you get a copy of the change notice you can find out what changed so that you can answer questions like this one:  [What is the change of "Airspace" here? Does it mean the airspace class of the airport has changed?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/95427/what-is-the-change-of-airspace-here-does-it-mean-the-airspace-class-of-the-ai)

Comment: So, as far as I understand, what we call change notices actually means a document that explains the changes in newly published charts since the previous charts. So what exactly do these numbers mean? Does it indicate how many pages or chapters the document describing the changes consists of? I don't think it indicates the total number of changes because when I compare the previous and new charts, I usually see that there are 10s of new changes.